# Help writing Apex Code to reduce CPU Usage caused by Autolaunched Flow

Tags: apex, soql

I am fairly new to Salesforce and have been working as an Admin for a couple months now so bear with me on this one.

We have customer data that we import each morning at 8:00 AM that populates the custom object Customer_Usage__c. There are roughly 900 records in the upload. This data consists of our customer's (hotels) metrics such as # of check-ins, method of check-in, etc.

We designed a Flow that would trigger off of the creation of a Customer_Usage__c record and would then perform the following:

1. Get the Account associated with each Customer_Usage__c record (one account per record)
2. Get the Customer_Usage__c records from the past 14 days from that account
3. Iterate through each of the Customer_Usage_c records from the last 14 days to add up the Occupancy (Occupancy_Today__c) and Average Daily Rate (ADR__c) then average by dividing by 14
4. Update the Account with those two averages to the following: Avg_Occ_Last_2_Weeks__c and Avg_ADR_Last_2_Weeks__c

The issue we are running into is that we have multiple other processes that are triggered by Account updates so we have a cascade of failures relating to CPU time limit and SOQL Query limit when the Account Update step is reached. I have attempted to filter the input criteria of the other flows so that they are not triggered unnecessarily but some need to always update on any account change.

I came across another StachExchange post where they recommended using a Batch Apex class to perform a similar bulk import. I do not have enough understanding of Apex to know whether writing a Batch Apex Class or ScheduleBatch Apex Class would be the best option, whether it should process asynchronously or synchronously, or if I would also need any Apex Triggers.

I was attempting to use the following sample as a template, but did not get too far and am unsure if this would be fitting for my need (from https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_batch):

```
public class UpdateContactAddresses implements
Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
// instance member to retain state across transactions
public Integer recordsProcessed = 0;
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(
        'SELECT ID, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, ' +
        'BillingPostalCode, (SELECT ID, MailingStreet, MailingCity, ' +
        'MailingState, MailingPostalCode FROM Contacts) FROM Account ' +
        'Where BillingCountry = \'USA\''
    );
}
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> scope){
    // process each batch of records
    List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
    for (Account account : scope) {
        for (Contact contact : account.contacts) {
            contact.MailingStreet = account.BillingStreet;
            contact.MailingCity = account.BillingCity;
            contact.MailingState = account.BillingState;
            contact.MailingPostalCode = account.BillingPostalCode;
            // add contact to list to be updated
            contacts.add(contact);
            // increment the instance member counter
            recordsProcessed = recordsProcessed + 1;
        }
    }
    update contacts;
}
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    System.debug(recordsProcessed + ' records processed. Shazam!');
    AsyncApexJob job = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors,
        JobItemsProcessed,
        TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
        FROM AsyncApexJob
        WHERE Id = :bc.getJobId()];
    // call some utility to send email
    EmailUtils.sendMessage(job, recordsProcessed);
}
```

The farthest I got was writing a SOQL call to get the roll-up of the last 14 days of the customer usage records for each account:

```
SELECT Account__c, SUM(Check_Ins_Kiosk__c), SUM(Check_Outs_Kiosk__c), SUM(Check_Ins_Web__c), SUM(Check_Outs_Web__c), SUM(Occupancy_Today__c), SUM(ADR__c) FROM Customer_Usage__c WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:14 GROUP BY Account__c
```

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated. I can provide any additional info if what I have described is insufficient.

Comment: As an alternative to updating the Account and/or other objects, you can build a report on top of `Customer_Usage__c` that shows you the occupancy metrics. This might be worth it since these are rolling stats.

Comment: `...we are running into is that we have multiple other processes that are triggered by Account updates ... a cascade of failures relating to CPU time limit and SOQL Query limit when the Account Update step is reached` - this tells me that you should be looking at all of these "other" processes and getting some of them to delegate work to async tasks as even if you solve this one issue, the next Flow that updates Accounts can run into the same issue. That said, step 4 could be an invocable Apex that in turn immediately delegated to a queueable apex which will have 60 sec CPU and 200 soql

Comment: @identigral We would ideally like to have that data present on the Account itself, but if this ends up becoming too much of a project that is definitely still a viable alternative. Thank you!

Comment: @Dallas Bridge You can roll up the stats onto a different object that is not Account and link that object to Account.

Comment: I had completely overlooked that you could have scheduled and asynchronous paths in flows so I implemented those into a few of the processes that were causing me trouble including the one mentioned above and it worked. Thank you all for the input!